# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que se ubiquen las imágenes generadas dentro de los divs?

Tags: javascript, flexbox

Buenos días/tardes/noches. Me gustaría saber si de casualidad sería posible ubicar un array de archivos de imágenes en el interior de una serie de divs. Estoy construyendo algo similar a un juego de memoria y no he sido capaz aún de hacer que el reverso de las cartas quede dentro del div que me hace de carta. Necesito una manera de poder conseguir que cada imagen se quede dentro de la carta en sí y no en el exterior. Intenté usar querySelector en vez de createElement pero tampoco sé exactamente cual de los dos sería más preciso de usar en este caso.

```js
const todasLasCartas = document.querySelector('.todasLasCartas');

const mazo = [];

mazo[0] = new Image();
mazo[0].src = 'img1.png';

mazo[1] = new Image();
mazo[1].src = 'img2.png';

mazo[2] = new Image();
mazo[2].src = 'img3.png';

mazo[3] = new Image();
mazo[3].src = 'img4.png';

mazo[4] = new Image();
mazo[4].src = 'img5.png';

mazo[5] = new Image();
mazo[5].src = 'img6.png';


function startNewGame() {
  generateRandomOrder(mazo);
  for (let i = 0; i < mazo.length; i++) {
      let carta = document.createElement('carta');
      carta.src = mazo[i].src; 
      carta.classList.add('reverso')
      todasLasCartas.appendChild(carta);
  }
}

    function generateRandomOrder(array) {
      for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        [array[i], array[j]] = [array[j], array[i]];
        
      }
      console.log(array);
      return array;
      
    }

startNewGame();
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

h1 {
    font-family: Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
    text-align: center;
}

.todasLasCartas {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 90%;
    padding-left: 5%;
}

#carta {
    box-sizing: border-box; 
    width: 170px; 
    height: 250px;
    background-color: greenyellow; 
    margin: 2%;  
    border:  5px solid;
}

.chiquita 
{
    max-width: 20px;
    max-height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Aplicación con Tabla</title>

<body>
    <h1> Empareja las frutas</h1>
    <div class="todasLasCartas">
            <div id="carta"></div>
            <div id="carta"></div>
            <div id="carta"></div>
            <div id="carta"></div>
            <div id="carta"></div>
            <div id="carta"></div>
            <div id="carta"></div>
            <div id="carta"></div>
            <div id="carta"></div>
            <div id="carta"></div>
            <div id="carta"></div>
            <div id="carta"></div>
    </div>
</body>

<script src="script.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: Ten siempre presente que [los id deben ser únicos en el DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id).

Answer (score -1):

bro primero que todo deberías cambiar en el HTML los id de las cartas y ponerlos como carta1,carta2,carta3,carta4..., eso es un consejo para que hagas uso de buenas prácticas y luego puedas acceder a una carta específica desde el código JavaScript si así lo deseas, luego aplica el estilo a estas cartas en CSS usando el selector de agrupación:#carta1,#carta2,#carta3, estos dos como ya te dije son consejos para que lleves una buena práctica, ahora vamos con tu problema... pero antes dejame decirte que me parece que al igual que yo eres un programador que recién está comenzando a aprender, yo también tengo la mayoría del tiempo problemas como los tuyos si quieres escríbeme a mi mail garciaacostaanthony@gmail.com para coordinar, ambos necesitamos ayuda y dos mentes juntas son más fuerte que las mismas por separado

```js
const todasLasCartas = document.querySelector('.todasLasCartas');

const mazo = [];
//primero hice un descarte de la instanciacion de los objetos images y solo almacené la URL en el arreglo. En corto verás el porqué hice eso.
mazo[0] = 'img1.png';

mazo[1] = 'img2.png';

mazo[2] = 'img3.png';

mazo[3] = 'img4.png';

mazo[4] = '.img5.png';

mazo[5] = 'img6.png';


function startNewGame() {
  generateRandomOrder(mazo);
  for (let i = 0; i < mazo.length; i++) {
  //el método createElement del objeto document crea un elemento HTML, por tanto, vamos a crear una imagen por cada vuelta de este bucle y no un elemento ("carta")
      let carta = document.createElement('img');
  //luego usamos el método setAttribute para asignarle un atributo al elemento img este va a ser el atributo de src, al cual como valor le vamos a pasar en cada vuelta a cada una de estas imágenes que se crean le pasamos las URL correspondientes del arreglo mazo
      carta.setAttribute("src", mazo[i]); 
      carta.classList.add('reverso')
 //y luego en cada vuelta del bucle le vamos a agregar un elemento hijo a cada hijo de (todasLasCartas) correspondiente a cada vuelta del bucle.
 todasLasCartas.children[i].appendChild(carta);
  }
}

    function generateRandomOrder(array) {
      for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        [array[i], array[j]] = [array[j], array[i]];
        
      }
      console.log(array);
      return array;
      
    }

startNewGame();
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

h1 {
    font-family: Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
    text-align: center;
}

.todasLasCartas {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 90%;
    padding-left: 5%;
}

#carta1,#carta2,#carta3,#carta4,#carta5,#carta6,#carta7,#carta8,#carta9,#carta10,#carta11,#carta12 {
    box-sizing: border-box; 
    width: 170px; 
    height: 250px;
    background-color: greenyellow; 
    margin: 2%;  
    border:  5px solid;
}

/*Estilo para que se acoplen las imagenes a las dimenciones del contenedor correspondiente*/
.reverso{
    width: 160px; 
    height: 245px;
}

.chiquita 
{
    max-width: 20px;
    max-height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Aplicación con Tabla</title>

<body>
    <h1> Empareja las frutas</h1>
    <div class="todasLasCartas">
            <div id="carta1"></div>
            <div id="carta2"></div>
            <div id="carta3"></div>
            <div id="carta4"></div>
            <div id="carta5"></div>
            <div id="carta6"></div>
            <div id="carta7"></div>
            <div id="carta8"></div>
            <div id="carta9"></div>
            <div id="carta10"></div>
            <div id="carta11"></div>
            <div id="carta12"></div>
    </div>
</body>

<script src="script.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: "Eso es un consejo para que hagas uso de buenas prácticas": ¿por qué en el CSS hacer referencia a los id de las cartas, si lo que se puede hacer (y es más legible, de hecho) es solamente crear _una clase_ para dar estilo a esos `div`?

Comment: Por otra parte: ¡estás dejando información sensible en un sitio **público**! Además, la ayuda se provee aquí en el sitio. [es.so] no es un gancho para proporcionar ayuda privada: la respuesta es para todos aquellos que lleguen a tener un problema similar, no solo para quien redactó la pregunta.

Comment: Es correcto, también puede crear una clase para el estilo de los divs y lo que me dices de la ayuda privada también es cierto, aunque creo que pierde sentido todo lo anterior al decirme que la ayuda es para todos y no solo para quien la redacto porque yo ya di mi respuesta ,ahora que yo quiera ayudar a la misma persona de forma privada no lo veo mal, valla con dios  @padaleiana